# Java ThreadLocal how to know if it is removed

Tags: java

In a method it runs like this:

```
interceptorMethod () {
    try {
        ContextHolder.init();
        doSomething();
    } finally {
        ContextHolder.clear();
    }
}
```

And ContextHolder is like this:

```
ContextHolder {
    ThreadLocal<Integer> data1 = new ...
    ThreadLocal<Integer> data2 = new ...
    init(int d1, int d2) {
       data1.set(d1)
       data2.set(d2)
    }
    
    clear() {
       data1.remove()
       data2.remove()
    }
    
    // getters and setters for data1 and data2
}
```

The problem shows up when `doSomething` is intercepted too, aka. `interceptorMethod` run twice. In this case, init() is called twice, and clear is also called twice, and clear cannot be called twice continuously.

So I am thinking to add a `ThreadLocal<Integer> counter`, thereafter init becomes like this:

```
ContextHolder {
    ThreadLocal<Integer> data1 = new ...
    ThreadLocal<Integer> data2 = new ...
    ThreadLocal<Integer> counter = new ...
    init(int d1, int d2) {
       // here, how do I know if counter is removed?
       isRemoved(counter)? counter.set(0): counter.set(counteger.get() + 1)
       data1.set(d1)
       data2.set(d2)
    }
    clear() {
       if ( 0 == minusCounter(counter)) {
           data1.remove()
           data2.remove()
           counter.remove()
       } 
    }
```

**Then how to detect if a ThreadLocal is already removed? isRemoved(counter)** Or is there a better way, not using counter, to achieve this?

Comment: Your clear method looks odd, why do you call `.get()` on the threadlocal? That won't remove the value …

Comment: You forgot the `<typeGoesHere>` on data1 and data2.

Comment: @knittl sorry, mistyped, already fix it from `get` to `remove`.

Comment: `ThreadLocal` has a `isPresent` method, `local.isPresent` can be used to check if a local variable is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provably you should use `ThreadLocal.withInitial()`?

```java
class ContextHolder {

    private final static ThreadLocal<String> DATA =
                    ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> "initial value");
    
}
```

It will initialize the thread local value once per thread.

[Java - Set the initial value for thread-local variable](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-book/set-the-initial-value-for-thread-local-variable.html)

Comment: once `counter.remove` is called, do I need to call `withInitial` again? If the answer is yes, how do I know it is removed.

Comment: I see. After reading doc for remove function, withIntial can reset its value once get is called after it's removed.